# How to wait for all useEffect Chain using Jest and Enzyme when all of them make asynchronous calls?

Tags: reactjs, promise, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

I have the following Minimal Component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { API } from "aws-amplify";


export default function TestComponent(props) {
  const [appointmentId, setAppointmentId] = useState(props.appointmentId);
  const [doctorId, setDoctorId] = useState(null);


  useEffect(() => {
    const loadDoctor = async () => {
      if (doctorId) {
        const doctorData = await API.post("backend", "/doctor/get", {
          body: {
            doctorId: doctorId
          }
        });
        console.log("This does not come", doctorData);
      }
    }
    loadDoctor();
  }, [doctorId])

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadAppointment = async () => {
      if (appointmentId) {
        const appointmentData = await API.post("backend", "/appointment/get", {
          body: {
            appointmentId: appointmentId
          }
        });
        console.log("This Loads", appointmentData);
        setDoctorId(appointmentData.doctorId);
      }      
    }
    loadAppointment();
  }, [appointmentId])
  
  return (
    <div>Testing Page</div>
  )
}
```

The Following `this does not work` not load wait for the `doctorId` `useEffect` `promise`.
But the second test `this does work` waits for both the `useEffect`

```
import React from "react";
import { API } from "aws-amplify";
import { mount } from "enzyme";
import { act } from "react-dom/test-utils";
import TestComponent from "./TestComponent.js";

jest.mock("aws-amplify");

beforeEach(() => {
API.post.mockImplementation((api, path, data) => {
  if (path === "/appointment/get") {
    return Promise.resolve({
      doctorId: "10000001"
    });
  }
  if (path === "/doctor/get") {
    return Promise.resolve({
      doctorName: "Mr. Doctor"
    });
  }
});

afterEach(() => {
  API.post.mockClear();
});

it("this does not work", async () => {
  const wrapper = mount(
    <TestComponent appointmentId={"2000001"}/>
  );
  await act(async () => {
    await Promise.resolve(wrapper);
    wrapper.update();
  });
  // this does not print the line console.log("This does not come", doctorData);
});

it("this does work", async () => {
  const wrapper = mount(
    <TestComponent appointmentId={"2000001"}/>
  );
  await act(async () => {
    await Promise.resolve(wrapper);
    wrapper.update();
    await act(async () => {
      await Promise.resolve(wrapper);
      wrapper.update();
    });
  });
  // this prints it. This works, but this is not scalable for more complicated code
});
```

Is there a way I can wait for all the subsequent `useEffect` and then test ?

Comment: I think your test makes sense since your component will need to run twice to get the doctor which means you have to update twice :)

Comment: But is there any good approach to test it ? I am quite new to React. First I do not know whether this useEffect chain is a good pattern or not. Secondly , if this is the way to do, then say tomorrow the code becomes more complicated, and it has more chains, so then my `act` function just keep on getting deeper which seems kind of anti pattern right ?

Comment: Hold on. It seems the theory of having the same number of calls between enzyme update + render times are wrong. I've just tried to make the test to be working in just one update. BTW what does it mean by writing `if (!doctorId) {`, it's supposed to have value then you call the API?

Comment: yes, this is a simplified version of my app. I first get an `appointmentId`, from that I get `doctorId`. So initially `doctorId` is set as `null`. I used the `if`, so that I do not call backend with the `null` `doctorId` in the first render. When the first `useEffect` on `appointmentId` finished, then it sets the `doctorId` and then in the subsequent `useEffect` we enter the `if` condition you mentioned. 
Note : Quite new to `react.js` so my terminology/concept might be a bit wrong.

Comment: I know what you wanted to do. But if you want to avoid to load doctor in case of no doctorId has been set, you have to write `if (doctorId) { /* then call api */}`. Why did you check `falsy` instead?

Comment: Oh Sorry that was a logical typo, now I made `if ( doctorId )` and `if (appointmentId) `. Now first appointment loads and then doctor loads. But the original problem still remains. In the first test, only the appointment promise is resolved and doctor promise is unresolved. Still blocked on that. Sorry for the logical code issue as I this was a typo. But the original problem still remains and I think now the question description is correct.

Answer (score -1):

I did something similar to preload images. this put all the promisse in a stack and wait for all to resolve

```
preloadImages(srcs) {
    function loadImage(src) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function() {
                resolve(img);
            };
            img.onerror = img.onabort = function() {
                reject(src);
            };
            img.src = src;
        });
    }
    var promises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < srcs.length; i++) {
        //const imgName = srcs[i].substring(15,18)
        //promises.push(loadImage(srcs[i]));
        promises.push(loadImage(images(`./${srcs[i]}.png`).default));
    }
    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

then.. prelaodImages(...).then(...

Comment: First thing, in my case, I cant do them with `all` as my second call depends on my first call's response. Secondly, are you proposing to change the source code ? But thats not a scalable approach right, the code behave perfectly in live. Changing code so that testing is easy is kind of anti-pattern right ? I know my approach might not be best, but I might test someone else's code as well.